# Matrix representation of Lie Algebra $B_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm writing some practical examples where to calculate the Killing form, the Cartan Matrix, Dynkin diagrams etc. Does anybody have on or two nice matrix representations of the $B_2$ Algebra?
It would be really apreciated.

Comment: You can generate such a representation yourself by picking a nondegenerate, symmetric bilinear form $B$ on $\Bbb C^5$, say with matrix representation $[B]$, in which case $B_2$ consists of the matrices in $X \in M(5, \Bbb C)$ such that $X^T [B] + [B] X = 0$. For the standard bilinear form this is just the set of skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: Note also that $B_2 \cong C_2$, so one can just as well pick a symplectic form $\omega$ on $\Bbb C^4$ and derive a similar linear condition that characterizes matrices in $M(4, \Bbb C)$.

Answer (score 3):

Two nice matrix representation are the *natural* and the *adjoint* representation. In fact, $B_2$ is the simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ of dimension $10$, so the natural representation is given by skew symmetric matrices of order $5$, i.e.,
$E_{ij}-E_{ji}$ for $i\neq j$ and $1\le i,j\le 5$. For example
$$
E_{12}-E_{21}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The adjoint representation is given by the linear operators $ad(x)$ defined by $ad(x)(y)=[x,y]$, which we can compute from the basis $(e_1,\ldots ,e_{10})$ of $\mathfrak{so}(5)$. There are many references for more concrete matrices, e.g., see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52259/matrices-of-lie-algebra-of-dynkin-diagram-b2).